# Chart - Date Order - Google Data Studio

Tags: sorting, charts, looker-studio

I'm doind a chart of warehouse income and outcome but X-Axis is not ordering the date correctly

Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the **Sort** parameter to you date dimension and use Ascending option for it.

Should look like this:

[image]

[Here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/topic/7059081?hl=en&ref_topic=9207420) you can find detailed docs for all the chart types used in GDS.